# Reading from a file and assigning content to a variable in Python

Tags: python

I have a ECC key value in a text file, a set of lines. I want to assign that value to a variable for further use. Though I can read the key value from the file, I have no idea as how to assign the value to a variable. I dont want it as an array. For example:

```py
variable = read(public.txt)
```

I'm on Python 3.4

Comment: Without seeing what's in `'public.txt'` we can't really tell you anything. Show an example of that file, and what value(s) you want out of it.

Comment: `variable = open('public.txt').read()`

Comment: MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEHERt50IOa5S03DPivsAMlg32uhJz
yWV7XRGvP/8ca416BffPrflDoPeGbxwdpsZxbPwj2psvf/sehgukSrKoAw==        @Cyber this is all the file has. And I want the variable to hold this value.

Comment: @PauloScardine thats what I was looking for. Thanks a ton. But it adds a newline character in the end. How I can strip it off?

Comment: `variable = open('public.txt').read().strip()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# Get the data from the file
with open('public.txt') as fp:
  v = fp.read()

# The data is base64 encoded. Let's decode it.
v = v.decode('base64')

#  The data is now a string in base-256. Let's convert it to a number
v = v.encode('hex')
v = int(v, 16)

# Now it is a number. I wonder what number it is:
print v
print hex(v)
```

Or, in python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import codecs

# Get the data from the file
with open('public.txt', 'rb') as fp:
  v = fp.read()

# The data is base64 encoded. Let's decode it.
v = codecs.decode(v,'base64')

#  The data is now a string in base-256. Let's convert it to a number
v = codecs.encode(v, 'hex')
v = int(v, 16)

# Now it is a number. I wonder what number it is:
print (v)
print (hex(v))
```

Comment: Add a `strip()` to fulfill the new requirements :)

Comment: i am not able to decode it, I am getting an attribute error as,                                 "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Comment: @AshKsh - Are you using Python3 or Python2?

Comment: Then my answer won't help you, @AshKsh. You should uncheck it until a Python3-compatible answer comes along.

Comment: Also, I assume that an ECC public key is just a (large) number. If it has some other internal structure, then you should say that in the question.

Comment: @AshKsh - I've added a Python3 version. I hope it helps.

Comment: @Robᵩ thanks a lot for taking this much time. It works to the perfection :)